# Trying to get Wordpress SEO to recognize custom post types

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

We're running a number of custom post types on a wordpress site and using the WordPress SEO plugin to assist with search optimisation, however the plugin doesn't recognise the Custom Post Types. Does anyone know if there's a way to get the plug-in to recognise the CTP's. The site is http://www.mrcharles.com.au

Answer (score 0):

When registering a custom post type make sure to add

```
'public' => true
```